# How can I use readframes() to get the audio file (wav) data in integers with Python?

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to get the file data after the header and translate it from hexadecimal to integers to use it to modify the sound but it seems that 'data' is an empty string from the beginning so the 'while' never starts. Any input is greatly appreciated!

```
Filenoun = '123.wav'
Sound = wave.open(Filenoun, 'rb')
data=Sound.readframes(2)

while data != '' :
    stream.write(data)
    data = int(binascii.hexlify(Sound.readframes(2)),8)
    print type(data)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Comment: No, the data is not an empty string.

Comment: Really ? Because I tried to "print len data" and I have a 0 and with "print type data" I have 'str' and with "print data" I have an empty space

Comment: Then maybe your file is empty?

Comment: No I'm sure of it because I can read it and hear it

Comment: Well, I just tried the above, and you do not get an empty string. Try another file.

Comment: Thanks it's almost working, I can print the data but then there's an error message like 50 times : "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 0: invalid start byte" which I don't understand

Comment: That's because what you get back is a bytes string, but when you print it gets converted to a unicode string, and it's not convertable to a unicode string. You can use `repr()` to get something printable for debugging.